# qbs cannot find the output of submodule (build with cmake)

Tags: cmake, git-submodules, qbs

I have a submodule built by cmake and successully build it in qbs script (see below code).

```
Product {
name: "mylib"
type: ["staticlibrary"]

// define buildScript, outputPath, libPrefix, libExt, cmakeBuildType, cmakeBuildConfig
// Note that outputPath is inside mylib folder, not qbs's build directory

Rule {
    multiplex: true
    outputArtifacts: [
        {
            filePath: product.outputPath + product.libPrefix + "lib1static" + product.libExt,
            fileTags: ["staticlibrary"]
        },
        {
            filePath: product.outputPath + product.libPrefix + "lib2static" + product.libExt,
            fileTags: ["staticlibrary"]
        }
    ]
    outputFileTags: ["staticlibrary"]
    prepare: {
        var cmd = new Command(product.buildScript, [product.outputPath, product.cmakeBuildType, product.cmakeBuildConfig]);
        cmd.description = "cmake generate mylib";
        cmd.workingDirectory = product.sourceDirectory + "/mylib/build_cmake";

        return [cmd];
    }
}
```

However, sometimes qbs delete the "lib1static" and "lib2static" and I get this error while linking:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '<path>/lib1static.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '<path>/lib2static.a'
```

I tried to debug but still don't know why. The first build can be successful with all output libraries are built, but in the next build, all libraries are disappeared.

Can anyone here explain and tell me which is the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the files would get deleted. However, there is another problem:
The rule as shown above will only run once, because it has no inputs, so changes in the source files of your sub-project will not get picked up.
(And, as a side note: If the outputs are not "dynamic", you can declare Artifact items, rather than using the outputArtifacts and outputFileTags properties.)
Try this:

```
Rule {
    multiplex: true
    alwaysRun: true
    Artifact {
        filePath: product.outputPath + product.libPrefix + "lib1static" + product.libExt
        fileTags: ["staticlibrary"]
        alwaysUpdated: false
    }
    Artifact {
        filePath: product.outputPath + product.libPrefix + "lib2static" + product.libExt
        fileTags: ["staticlibrary"]
        alwaysUpdated: false
    }
    prepare: {
        var cmd = new Command(product.buildScript, [product.outputPath, product.cmakeBuildType, product.cmakeBuildConfig]);
        cmd.description = "cmake generate mylib";
        cmd.workingDirectory = product.sourceDirectory + "/mylib/build_cmake";

        return [cmd];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand more the difference between outputArtifacts and Artifact. I changed my scripts  your suggestion. Still get the output libraries get deleted somehow :(

Comment: I don't see why that would happen. Are you sure it is qbs that is deleting the files? You can try running with -v; redirect the stderr output to a file and check the output for "removing".

Comment: As you've suggested, I ran qbs with -v but saw no "removing", "remove" or "delete". I wasn't sure that qbs has deleted those libs, so I wrote some commands to copy all libs to another folder (outputPath) after cmake build and then link qbs to libs in that outputPath. I also tried to link qbs with only 1 of 5 libs, unfortunately when errors happened sometimes, only linked lib was deleted, others still there on outputPath. So I guess qbs deleted it. Any clue?

Comment: I'm not aware of any code that removes files without such a debug message.